# Fourier transform of entire function of exponential type $\nu$ equal to zero outside $\Delta_\nu$

Tags: fourier-transform, entire-functions

Let $\Delta_\nu=\{|x_j|<\nu,j=1,...,n\}$
definition of entire function of exponential type $\nu$.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N},~\nu>0 $. A function
$g: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C} $ is an entire function if the following properties hold

1. It can be written as power series $~$ $z=(z_1,...,z_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n$: for some $a_{k_1,\dots ,k_n}\in \mathbb{C}$
   \begin{equation}
        g(z)=\sum_{k_1=0}^\infty\dots\sum_{k_n=0}^\infty a_{k_1,\dots ,k_n}z_1^{k_1}\dots z_n^{k_n}
       \end{equation}
   for any  $z_1,...,z_n\in \mathbb{C}$,\
2. $\forall\varepsilon>0 \quad\exists A_\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $z\in\mathbb{C}^n$ the following inequality holds

$$
   |g(z)| \leq A_\varepsilon e^{({\nu}+\varepsilon)(|z_1|+|z_2|+\dots+|z_n|)}.
$$

Let $g\in L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$

> How do I prove that the Fourier transform of entire function g of exponential type $\nu$ is equal to zero outside $\Delta_\nu$?